# SharePoint 2013 Managed Property not returning any values in Design Template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search

My Custom SharePoint Managed Property is not showing any values when I add it in the design template.
The property has values for sure as I did check it using a custom WebPart that ) created using C#.

What things could I check?

Comment: PLease append the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved
Steps:-

- Go to WebPart Edit it.
- Go to Display Templates
- Select Use a single template to display items and select the display template
- Add your Managed Property in Hit-highlighted properties(JSON)

That's It

Comment: It sounds like you did not define a Result Type for your Display Template. Your result will work, but must be configured on every search result web part. If you create a result type rule it will display every time.

Comment: I tried most of the steps in all the blogs and finally consolidated the steps that actually worked for me. Follow this for resolution. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233781/manually-added-managed-property-is-not-showing-on-a-customised-search/233898#233898

Answer (score 1):

Have you used property sync.

Go to Site settings --> Search Result Types. Notice that a Property Sync alert is displayed.

More info here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/09/17/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-the-hover-panel-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx

Comment: Checked. Nothing found there :(. The value is multiline a big string is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the steps in all the blogs and finally consolidated the steps that actually worked for me.
Follow [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233781/manually-added-managed-property-is-not-showing-on-a-customised-search/233898#233898) for resolution

Update: Adding the solution here

Ensure below:

1. Managed properties are properly mapped to required crawled properties
2. Do a full crawl
3. Ensure that the display template (if edited by adding the new managed property) is uploaded and published
4. Ensure that the "Update" link in the notification bar is clicked in Result types screen (better to check both at spweb and spsite levels)
5. Clear browser cache

Perform a search now and see if the new MP is coming up.
If still they are not showing up, use the Search [SearchQueryToolv2.6](https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) to query and find if the Search API is throwing them up. If all seems fine then do below

Final nail in the coffin would be **restarting the SP Timer and SP Administration services**. (This step made my changes reflect. Though for others, it worked at step 5)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85702)

Comment: @Gaurravs it sure is preferred to extend the answer, but in this case the link refers to sharepoint.stackexchange. The link basically can't become invalid unless this site becomes invalid.

Comment: @Moe its always better to include some part of answer which is main key to solution. more details can be found on the link.

Comment: If solution is already part of the forum previously. then question seems to be duplicated off